# Eclipse run a spring boot application with MavenDependencies in classpath taken from a maven profile

Tags: eclipse, maven, jhipster

I have a spring boot project that run correctly when launched from maven mvn -P dev spring-boot:run.

When I start it as a java application it fails because of several ClassNotFoundException.  It's due to the fact that some dependencies belong to dev maven profile so they're not present in Maven Dependencies that eclipse put in classpath when it launchs java appication.

So the question is: how can I obtain the correct Maven Dependencies choosing a particular maven profile?

Comment: Why do you have dependencies in a profile that's bad idea...

Comment: In a spring boot app it's even worse can you explain?